# error in double value

Tags: c

```
char *format_double_trans_amount(double amount)

{

   char amount_array_n[25];

   strcpy(amount_array_n,""); 

   printf("\nInitial  value ***** %s",amount_array_n);

   printf("\nDouble amount ***** %f",amount);

   sprintf(amount_array_n,"%1f",amount);

   printf("\nFinal ........ %s",  amount_array_n);

   printf("\nReturn ---- %s",amount_array_n);

   return amount_array_n;
}

int main()
{

printf ("\nformat_format_double_trans_amount: %s ************", format_double_trans_amount(1000.123400));

}
```

the result in the main method gives dump value could anybody please help me on this?
output:

Initial  value *****

Double amount ***** 1000.123400

Final ........ 1000.123400

Return ---- 1000.123400

format_format_double_trans_amount: /ò# ($$Ð/Òð

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are returning a pointer to **amount_array_n** at end of the function **format_double_trans_amount()**, however the scope of that stack allocated array is limited to the body of the function. Trying to access that memory area after exiting the function will result in undefined behaviour (at best rubbish displayed and at worst a crash).

The quick and dirty fix to your program is adding static to amount_array_n:

```
static char amount_array_n[25];
```

That would make the array an effective global variable. Still, not a very elegant solution, just a quick fix for your test program.

Answer (score 2):

You are returning the reference of a local variable which is what causing the problem.

```
char amount_array_n[25];
```

`amount_arra_n` is a character array residing on stack which gets invalidated up on return of the function call.

Comment: no when i  char amount_array_n[25];  decrese the value like amount_array_n[12]; its giving the result?

Comment: @jcrshankar - This is undefined behavior. The standard says it can do anything. The code can appear to work, but that doesn't make it right.

Comment: @jcshankar - If you are getting result, then you are **unlucky**. It seems like working because probably stack might not have deallocated the stack variable.

Answer (score 2):

`amount_array_n` being local to the function gets destroyed after the function returns. Using the returned value would invoke Undefined Behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

When your function returns, the character array it allocated is deallocated, so when you return a pointer to that array, the pointer becomes invalid. Returning it is undefined behavior, which means the compiler can do anything. If you're really unlucky, it'll work, and you won't realize you have a problem until years later when your whole program breaks and you have no idea why. In most cases, you get garbage values or crashes.

If you want the function to return a pointer to an array, you need to dynamically allocate it, or pass in a buffer (and the buffer's size) for the function to write into.

Comment: but when i decrese the array size  char amount_array_n[25] to like amount_array_n[12]; its giving the result?

Comment: @jcrshankar - I saw your comment above, and amended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

amount_array_n is local variable, when you return its pointer to main function, it won't have a valid address that's why you get that output.